# How to paint outdoor conduit?

Tags: painting, conduit

I want to paint my conduit on an old brick house entryway so that it blends in more - ideally a oil-rubbed brass or brown color to fit the historical character.

How would I apply the paint - does it need to be pre-treated with something besides degreaser or regular primer?  I'm guessing I would have to paint it after the conduit is installed to make sure the grounded nature of the metal connections is sound?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends.

If it's galvanized metal, let it age for 6 months or so, so the zinc develops a "patina".  Painting clean zinc is like trying to paint a mirror lol.  Use "oil based" primer - at the least KILZ Original, but others will do - Rustoleum is particularly good on metal.  You need to use a natural bristle brush - nylon brushes will not work with alkyd. Use cheap "chip brushes" and throw them in the trash at the end of the job.  If you don't want to deal with the smelly stuff, "rattle can" spray paint *is that exact same stuff*, you can either do a great job masking and spray directly, or you can spray it into a cup and brush-paint it.

If you have PVC pipe, just get a 3M Scotchbrite pad like for pots and pans, and use that to "scuff sand" it - not real sanding, just to knock the gloss off so paint will stick without a fight. (this won't work on zinc). Then you can use an alkyd or latex **primer** on the PVC. Alkyd will perform a little bit better IMO.

Again, on galvanized pipe, do *no surface preparation at all* - if you sand it you'll have to wait another 6 months for it to gain another patina.

Once the prep is done, do a wipedown with soap and lots of clean water, or ideally, paint thinner.

Once the primer is on, topcoat to suit.

Answer (score 4):

Using a primer made specifically for galvanized metal is advisable - there are many options. So, clean, prime, paint. Yes, after installation.